# Best regression model where some fields may be intentionally blank for some samples

Tags: regression, data-science

I'm looking to build a regression model where I have time based variables that may or may not exist for each data sample.

For instance, let's say we wanted to build a regression model where we could predict how long a new car will last. One of the values is when the car gets its first servicing. However, there are some samples where the car never gets serviced at all. In these situations, how can I account for this when building the model? Can I even use a linear regression model or will I have to choose a different regression model?

When I think about it, this is basically the equivalent of having 2 fields: one for whether the car was serviced and if that is true, a second field for when. But I'm not sure how to build a regression that has data that is intentionally missing.

Answer (score 0):

Apply regression without using time-series. To try to capture seasonality in the data, encode the date/time columns into binary columns (to represent year, day of year, day of the month and day of the week etc.).

Comment: I would love to understand more, as I am new to this field. Should I be trying to avoid these sorts of variables is what you are saying? Or try to recode it? Even if I try to capture seasonality, it doesn't help if the data sometimes isn't there.

Comment: @Deepak :  It would be helpful if you can mention the columns you have in your dataset. What are the time based variables you are talking about?

Comment: Yea, I think I can give a cleaner example. In order to figure out how long the car will last, one of the variables I have is time of the first accident. For cars that had accidents, the car lasts a shorter period of time. However, it's not really a boolean, the time of the accident affects when the life of the car ends. How do I model an independent variable that may be in a sample and the value isn't categorical when it exists, but numeric?

Comment: @Deepak - Can you specify the format of the 'time of the first accident'? Also since you are predicting the life of a car you must also be having Purchase Date as well as End of Life date. Correct?

Comment: @Deepak - What I meant in the answer section is, to apply One Hot Encoding on date and time columns.